# how to cover full button width on hover in html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hover

**Button without hover:**

[image: Button without hover]

**Button on hover**:

[image: Button on hover]

I started to code a website but left with some styling errors.
How can I cover that part left on button while **hovering**. Every time i hover that part is unhovered.

**HTML** code for that button(full menu) is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendor/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendor/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/generic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.3.0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/js-image-slider.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/resources/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/resources/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/resources/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/resources/favicons/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/resources/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/resources/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- *******************************-->
    <!--         First ROW MENU         -->
    <!-- *******************************-->
    <nav>
      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul class="row">
          <li class="btn"><a href="http://onourem.com/onourem-ambassador-funship.html" target="_blank">funship program details</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/pdf/alumnimeet2018.pdf" target="_blank">alumni &amp; fairwell meet-2018</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/img/add30102017.jpg">requirment: faculty/other staff</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/pdf/information_brochure.pdf" target="_blank">information brochure</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/pdf/admission_form.pdf" target="_blank">download form</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="#">student grievance</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

**CSS** code for that button (full menu) is :

```css
/*=================================Common=================*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

p {
  font-weight: 500;
}


/*========================resuable=============*/

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.box {
  padding: 1%;
}

.list-item a:link,
.list-item a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.list-item a:hover,
.list-item a:active {
  color: #4285f4;
}


/*==============================Heading====================*/

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  word-spacing: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 180%;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/*====================Button=========================*/

.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.24);
}


/*==============================main-nav====================*/

.main-nav {
  background-color: #535353;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #929292;
  font-size: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**thanks for the help in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Its because of newline characters when you use inline-block, add font-size:0 to the ul and font-size:12px to li can fix the problem

```css
/*=================================Common=================*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

p {
  font-weight: 500;
}


/*========================resuable=============*/

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.box {
  padding: 1%;
}

.list-item a:link,
.list-item a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.list-item a:hover,
.list-item a:active {
  color: #4285f4;
}


/*==============================Heading====================*/

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  word-spacing: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 180%;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/*====================Button=========================*/

.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.24);
}


/*==============================main-nav====================*/

.main-nav {
  background-color: #535353;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #929292;
  font-size: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendor/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendor/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/generic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.3.0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/js-image-slider.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/resources/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/resources/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/resources/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/resources/favicons/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/resources/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/resources/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- *******************************-->
    <!--         First ROW MENU         -->
    <!-- *******************************-->
    <nav>
      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul class="row">
          <li class="btn"><a href="http://onourem.com/onourem-ambassador-funship.html" target="_blank">funship program details</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/pdf/alumnimeet2018.pdf" target="_blank">alumni &amp; fairwell meet-2018</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/img/add30102017.jpg">requirment: faculty/other staff</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/pdf/information_brochure.pdf" target="_blank">information brochure</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="resources/pdf/admission_form.pdf" target="_blank">download form</a></li>
          <li class="btn"><a href="#">student grievance</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```